# ImportError: No module named 'svmutil'

Tags: libsvm

i get stuck right now, my code:

```
import sys
import os
import itertools
import random
from PIL import Image
from svmutil import *
DIMENSION = 200
ROOT_DIR = "../train/"
NEGATIVE = "negative"
POSITIVE = "positive"
CLASSES = [NEGATIVE, POSITIVE]
....
```

and it says :

```
ImportError: No module named 'svmutil'
```

now I use python 3.5
What should I do now?

Comment: MIght use this insted  `sys.path.append('thatdirectory')` then import, check you have svmutil installed using pip.

Comment: where i make that code ? I'm sorry because I am still a beginner for using python. Btw I am using anaconda to run python @LethalProgrammer

Comment: How to use it? Iam sorry because I am still beginner for using this python

Comment: Thanks @LethalProgrammer, it works.. but I have another problem, it said